# Aptana Studio 3 combine php with html

Tags: php, html

hi guys am having problems mixing P.H.P code into an HTML file i get error on P.H.P that says missing end tags any help please

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are missing something, either you are not saving the file with ".php" extension.
And also there were some errors in your code. you was putting semicolon at the end of HTML tag. whci is not practiced.
Following is the code which is running successfully.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <title>New Web Project</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>New Web Project Page</h1> 
        <?php echo "string"; ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```